# Can iTunes find all songs with no Album Art?

Tags: itunes, windows, album-art

I want to find all songs or tracks which don't have Album Art associated with them in my iTunes music library.  I want to do this so that I can fix Album Art problems in advance of a backup.  How can I have iTunes show me just these tracks?

My iTunes library is on a Windows 7 PC.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do this by creating a Smart Playlist:

(I'm using a Mac, but it will be similar for you)

[image]

Set the "Album Artwork" rule to "false":
[image]

This will update automatically as you add artwork to your albums. And you can simply delete this playlist when you're done.

Comment: FWIW, it was "Has Artwork" instead of "Album Artwork" in my iTunes (v10.6.0.40).

Comment: I tried to do this bit It doesn't have the album art false feature, is this only for Macs ? I can create the smart playlist though, just cannot filter out songs without art

Answer (score 3):

With the new iTunes 11, the smart playlist has a new filter labelled "Has Artwork". Simply set that to false, and there's your songs without artwork!

Answer (score 0):

Sounded like a good answer but on my itunes on Macbook Air, this finds 439 songs with no artwork, yet many of them when I look at them in the playlist, I see album artwork.  Even odder, some of the songs in the same album, having the same artwork, make the list while others don't.

I have used Doug Scripts to find songs with missing artwork
http://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/scripts13.php

Comment: iTunes will show you artwork if one song of the album has the artwork, but that does not mean that all songs have the artwork embedded. Because of that it can happen that when you only transfer one song of the album to your iPhone/iPod that does not have the artwork embedded that then the iPhone/iPod is not able to display the artwork.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get all the album artwork for your songs or albums I recommend you find a program that gets metadata for your songs. Like I use TuneUp on my mac and it gave all my albums with no artwork an artwork that is one of the ones for your album.